My solution for 2125. Number of Laser Beams in a Bank of leetcode is not passing all the testcases. 142 / 147 testcases passed
So my code is not passing all the test cases for the problem wherein you have to return the total number of laser beams in the bank.
class Solution:
    def numberOfBeams(self, bank: List[str]) -> int:
        for x in bank:
            if(x.count("1")==0):
                bank.remove(x)
        res = 0
        for i in range(len(bank)):
            if(i==(len(bank)-1)):
                break
            else:
                res = res + bank[i].count("1")*bank[i+1].count("1")   
        return res

Here's the code
My approach is to count the number 0f 1's and multiply with the next row and do this repetitively to get the total amount of laser
But for some elements the number of 1's is 0 so for that i have this part
for x in bank:
    if(x.count("1")==0):
        bank.remove(x)

But for the last 5 test cases its not working

Leetcode has a separate discussion forum where you can post your doubts. This is not the right place.

Stackoverflow can be the right place for leetcode questions, but don't expect anybody to be  familiar with the questions or the leetcode platform. Make sure you include all relevant detail. The leetcode number is meaningless here, instead describe the problem your code should solve. We also don't know what tests you run, so you'll need to include the (failing) tests. See [ask].

Removing elements from a list while iterating over it is never a good idea. In your case it will cause it to skip some elements.
Similar example:
>>> o = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> for e in o:
...     o.remove(e)
...
>>> o
[2, 4]

Instead of this, use list comprehension or iterate over a copy of that list.
List comprehension:
bank = [row for row in bank if '1' in row]

Using a copy:
for x in bank.copy():
    if '1' not in x:
        bank.remove(x)

